# Relation between martial arts and psychodelics?

Tags: training, recommendation, health, strength, power

I had my trip on LSD a few weeks ago. Every since, my fighting style has been EXPONENTIALLY climbing up. Not to mention my levels of energy, or my body awareness. I now need no trainers telling me what body part to work on after this one, how intense, for how long I should be fighting for best results and so on. It just comes natural. Not only that, but the intensity and endurance of which I do the exercises or the whole trainings is litterally times more. This, and much more but it'd be way too long to write everything here. What I wrote is enough to get why I'm asking this question.

So, what is known about psychodelics and martial arts? Please, don't go with the, "you should be very cautious" apporoach. Or you can achieve same results without psychodelics. Although this is a very proper question, I'd prefer to keep it separate.

P.S. This is not only my experience, i.e. there are plenty of other martial artist that can say the same.

Comment: Has anyone you've trained with mentioned your improvements?

Comment: Close as medical advice and possible RICO violation.

Comment: If you type *Martial Arts psychedlics* in Google, you actually get a number of people discussing this, but most of them are either speculative or discussing psychedelics related to philosophy/religion in martial arts. The others indicate that some people have felt increased focus (and claim others have seen the same in them) combined with relaxation and a feeling that they understand all of the angles and how their biomechanics contribute. Interesting stuff, actually, but all anecdotal.

Answer (score 2):

What you perceive to have changed has not necessarily changed in the manner you understand it to. The psychotropic you ingested altered your perception of reality, and not the way you interact with it. Because of the way that LSD bonds with your neuroreceptors, you are likely to have long-term (to permanent) effects from it. Those effects are distortions of your sensory input.

In other words, LSD didn't give you a deeper understanding of martial arts. It just makes you feel like you have.

Comment: Yeah, unless you have verification that there's been any improvement on your part from folks who know how well you move, etc. odds are almost certain that this is just the drugs affecting your self perception. And while people involved in pretty much ANY activity claim to feel improved, it's notable psychotropic drugs are not the choice chemical for engaging in warfare.

Comment: LSD is definitely not considered performance enhancing.

Answer (score 0):

Martial arts practice has a lot to do with the feedback from your own body and so in some ways, it may help you break through some barriers. It may also improve your speed while under its effects, but having familiarity with LSD in my youth as a guitarist, I felt like I was breaking new ground - listening back later when I was off the drug, it was nothing special. Besides, even if it does help you in your movements and perception, you are training with LSD as part of your practice - is this something you plan to do every day of your life - include a drug as part of your training in order to gain its benefits? I've practiced martial arts daily for 35 years - there's no way I could have done LSD as part of my training every day for 35 years!